# Problem deploying WPF application

Tags: wpf, deployment, .net-4.0

I created an installer for it, installed .NET Framework 4 on target machine. However, my application didn't work. I've got a message, that is has stopped working and offered to send a report.

Windows log:
The name of the offending module: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7600.16385
Exception Code: 0xe0434352
Offset error: 0x00009617

Answer (score 0):

This could be many things.  Ensure the correct .net runtimes are installed.  Insure permissions are correct on all files.  Did you forget to deploy some dependencies?  Check the fusion log.  Check the system log.

Do you have logging in your application?  How far does the app get before crashing?  We need LOTs of info before we can even start to help.

Answer (score 0):

Insufficient information to give a meaningful answer.

Check your Windows event log log (administrative tools | event viewer | windows logs | application) and find the real error.

Comment: Are you sure that error is the one generated when your app crashes?